# Replacing characters in an NSString after converting an NSDictionary to an NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

I've searched around and couldn't find an answer, so forgive me if I've created a duplicate question.

I've converted an NSDictionary into an NSString and would like to take out all the occurrences of "{", "}", and ";". When I use `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` nothing appears different in the NSLog.

The code I've written:

```
NSString *myString = [myDictionary description];
[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"{" withString:@""];
[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"}" withString:@""];
[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @";" withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", myString);
```

Comment: Rather than use the `description` method, which is logging, why not iterate through the dictionary and convert it to a string without the {}; in the first place.  If you had more information on the format you want for keys vs values I could suggest some code

Comment: Also, the reason that nothing appears different is that the `stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString` returns a new string that you need to assign to `myString`, it doesn't mutate the string in place

Comment: @Paulw11 I would love some help. The reason that I was using `description` was because the dictionary that I'm trying format is a dictionary inside of a dictionary. I would like to keep the format that `description` gives, but I just want to take out the brackets and semi-colons.

Comment: If you used `description`, don't.  It is only intended for diagnostics, and is not considered reliable for "production" use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that nothing appears different is that the stringByReplacingOccurencesOfString returns a new string that you need to assign to myString, it doesn't mutate the string in place, so you could use

```
NSString *myString = [myDictionary description];
myString=[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"{" withString:@""];
myString=[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @"}" withString:@""];
myString=[myString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @";" withString:@""];

NSLog(@"%@", myString);
```

But, generally the use of `description` for anything other that debugging/logging should be avoided.  You should iterate the dictionary directly - For example.

```
NSMutableString *myString=[NSMutableString new];
for (NSString *key in myDictionary.allKeys) {
    [myString appendString:@"%@ = %@\r\n",key,myDictionary[key]];
}

NSLog(@"%@",myString");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet` and `stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString` api both. Refer the below sample code:-

```
NSString *myString = [myDictionary description];
NSString *str=[myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"{}"]];
NSLog(@"%@", [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@";" withString:@""]);
```